# Xamarin: Mono.Linker.MarkException Microsoft.AppCenter.Push.dll Failed to resolve Firebase.Iid.FirebaseInstanceIdService

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

Someone can help with this problem?

```
Error   Mono.Linker.MarkException: Error processing method: 'System.Void Microsoft.AppCenter.Push.TokenService::OnTokenRefresh()' 
in assembly: 'Microsoft.AppCenter.Push.dll' ---> Mono.Cecil.ResolutionException: Failed to resolve Firebase.Iid.FirebaseInstanceIdService   
   at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.HandleUnresolvedType(TypeReference reference)
   at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.MarkType(TypeReference reference)
   at MonoDroid.Tuner.MonoDroidMarkStep.MarkType(TypeReference reference)
   at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.MarkType(TypeReference reference)
   at MonoDroid.Tuner.MonoDroidMarkStep.MarkType(TypeReference reference)
   at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.ProcessMethod(MethodDefinition method)
   at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.ProcessQueue()
```

This error happen only in Release profile, not in debug profile.

After much testing I realized that it looks like a visual studio problem not a DLL.

I tried to go back to a version that a few months ago compiled without problems and now gives the same error.

Thanks to anyone who answers

Comment: With Xcode 12.1 no error, with xcode 12.2 error: '_OBJC_CLASS_$_MSAppCenterUserDefaults' could not be found in any of the libraries or frameworks linked

Comment: A, According to your error message, I find this thread that said **App Center Push will be removed from the SDK in next version**. For detailed info, please take a look: [AppCenter 3.4.3 uses derecated FirebaseInstanceIdService](https://github.com/microsoft/appcenter-sdk-dotnet/issues/1457)

Comment: Thank, but i don't use Xamarin.Firebase.Iid and i use Microsoft.AppCenter packages (v. 3.4.1)

Comment: Update: with iOS ver. all work fine. The problem is only in Android ver.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't a real solution.
Migrate following the [Push Migration Guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/migration/push/)

thanks and good luck